# Using RestTemplate to call Sprinf based rest Web Service (using JSON)

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

I am doing some POC where there is a spring based rest web service consumed from a html page having JQuery code. I use $.json for this. 
Set up is : Spring 4 with Jaxson 2.3 and Jquery 1.10
When I try to hit the rest ws directly using absolute url like protocol://ip:port/contextroot/resourceurl from $.json, I get correct response. 
However, I got another task lately to get this call done from inside another controller in same web application instead of jquery. So now what I am trying to do is, call a spring controller from  $.json, which creates RestTemplate call and make the webservice call. This seems to be working because the web service is actually hit and the proper result is also prepared. However when the web service tries to return, my code breaks, giving me following exception :

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [regionserv] in context with path [/lmpamfsWebApp] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class [Lcom.leggmason.lmpamfs.beans.CodeLookupBean;] and content type [text/plain;charset=UTF-8]] with root cause
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class [Lcom.leggmason.lmpamfs.beans.CodeLookupBean;] and content type [text/plain;charset=UTF-8]
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:108)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:549)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:502)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:239)
    at com.leggmason.lmpamfs.controllers.RegionController.fetch(RegionController.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:339)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:409)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1044)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/region1", method = RequestMethod.GET,headers="Accept=application/json", produces = "application/json")
    public ModelAndView fetch() throws Exception{
        System.out.println("Inside rest controller body");

        restTemplate= new RestTemplate();
        List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();


        messageConverters.add(jsonMessageConverter);
        messageConverters.add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
        restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);
        List<CodeLookupBean> region = Arrays.asList(restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:9080/lmpamfsWebApp/region", CodeLookupBean[].class));



        return new ModelAndView(jsonView_i, DATA_FIELD, region);
    }
```

Rest body :

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/region", method = RequestMethod.GET,headers="Accept=application/json", produces = "application/json")
    public ModelAndView fetchRegion() throws Exception{
        System.out.println("Inside rest body");
        List<CodeLookupBean> region = props.getRegion();
        return new ModelAndView(jsonView_i, DATA_FIELD, region);
}
```

I have tried following information made available at :
http://blog.jdriven.com/2012/11/consume-rest-json-webservices-easily-using-spring-web/
https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/

I will appreciate any help to fix this issue. Also it will be great if learning resurces for Spring RestTemplate based get and post, end to end is made available to me.

Thanks,
Suvojit

Comment: content type [text/plain;charset=UTF-8] is the problem.  It needs to be application/json

Comment: @NathanielJohnson Yes that is what I suspected. But I dont understand how is contenttype becomming text/plain. I have used produces = "application/json".
In fact, if I directly call the web service, it gives me a perfect json string data. I fail to understand why does it give me [text/plain;charset=UTF-8] content type data when I call it via spring controller.
Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: Which version of Spring are you using? When returning a ModelAndView, I think that the "produces" hint is not taken into account.

Comment: @n1r3 I am using Spring4. 
I would like to mention that if I call web service directly, it produces the json data correctly. Why then it ignores the produces hint the other time?

Comment: With the correct headers?

Comment: @n1r3 : headers="Accept=application/json", anything else required?

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't be more helpful. When I did similar POCs with Spring, Jersey, and RESTEasy, I eventually pitched them all and went with a simple servlet parser and the Jackson/JSON libraries.  I found it nearly impossible to debug REST services sitting on a framework.  See this answer for a version of what I do with a straight servlet container. http://stackoverflow.com/a/18960697/1085699