# Returning data from spring DAO layer to spring Service layer

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dao

Currently I am executing a sql query inside a spring dao layer method which returns me a java ResultSet object. I am directly returning this ResultSet Object to the spring service layer. Want to know, is it a good way to return the complete ResultSet? if not then in what form we should return the result set to the service layer if we get different name and no. of columns in the ResultSet based on some conditions when we query the db.

Comment: personally I prefer to keep the service separated from "infrastructure implementation" than in your case is you are querying the db with jdbcTemplate I will ad a rowMapper inside the DAO(or repository)and return only domain object to the service. This way you can decide to chenge the DAO implementation(passing to another database for instance) without touching the services

Comment: I don't know, the idea of marshaling a results set into a POJO seems quaint and old-fashioned in 2018.

Comment: Might convert it to json if I was just passing it to the front end (without any value classes or whatever we call them).  Like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18960446/how-to-convert-a-java-resultset-into-json.   If I had to be on the jvm and I was given complete freedom would do it in clojure and would just use the built in clojure data structures.

Comment: @RobertMoskal : You skipped one layer. What if you need that data in your business logic, i.e. service layer, to be able to make a critical decision?

Comment: Arguably, if you have complex biz logic.  But if you are just templating some data, then no.  I would also say, that it's also unnecessary if you are just transforming, filtering, or decorating a results set.  Better to have 100 functions working on one data structure than 10 classes working on 10 data structures.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of returning a `ResultSet`, you should think about returning a `Collection` (`Set`, `List`, etc.) of entity objects. Your DAO would usually read from the `ResultSet`, make a `Collection` of entity objects from it and then return it to the service layer. What you are currently doing is exposing implementation details of your persistence layer to the service layer. If you change your persistence to, say, Hibernate, you would need to change your service layer too.

Also, if you have queries which fetch different amounts of columns from the same table, you can return different types of entity objects from your DAO, such as `BasicUserDetails` (contains only a basic set of attributes) and `UserDetails` (contains all attributes). If you want your persistence layer to be that dynamic, you need to make sure your service layer understands what kind of data is being returned.

Answer (score 1):

Your DAO must return collection of object. Do not return ResultSet.
Service layer is where you perform your business logic. What we are actually doing is creating adapter interfaces to access business objects. So your service classes should not have anything other than business logic.